# Image clipping around the text

Tags: graphics, clip, cutwin

If there any latex package available for clipping the images. Here I using cutwin package, but it will produce tedious work to fix the text around the images. Here we have more images like that, we faced challenge to fix each and every images.

Please suggest me improve my quality and reduce the manual intervention. Here I attached screenshot for your reference

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{cutwin,wrapfig,graphicx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample chapter}


In this topic, we have learned about the sharp rise and fall of one of the world's greatest empires, as well as the leaders at the heart of it. The Yuan dynasty was full of contrasts, from its violent conquests to its tolerance of different beliefs and promotion of multicultural city centres. We also considered the different experiences of those living within the Mongols realm during their century-long rule.\clearpage


\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}}
%\begin{cutout}{3}{130pt}{130pt}{8}
%In this topic, we have learned about the sharp rise and fall of one of the world's greatest empires, as well as the leaders at the heart of it. The Yuan dynasty was full of contrasts, from its violent conquests to its tolerance of different beliefs and promotion of multicultural city centres. We also considered the different experiences of those living within the Mongols realm during their century-long rule.
%In this topic, we have learned about the sharp rise and fall of one of the world's greatest empires, as well as the leaders at the heart of it. The Yuan dynasty was full of contrasts, from its violent conquests to its tolerance of different beliefs and promotion of multicultural city centres. We also considered the different experiences of those living within the Mongols realm during their century-long rule.
%\end{cutout}


\renewcommand*{\putstuffinpic}{%
\put(0,-50){\makebox(0,0){\includegraphics[height=94pt]{c01uf027.pdf}}}}

%\opencutright
\begin{shapedcutout}{3}{9}{%
165pt,165pt,%x
140pt,150pt,%
110pt,105pt,%
100pt,105pt,%
135pt,110pt,%
133pt,130pt,%
128pt,155pt,%
115pt,160pt,
110pt,170pt}
In this topic, we have learned about the sharp rise and fall of one of the world's greatest empires, as well as the leaders at the heart of it. The Yuan dynasty was full of contrasts, from its violent conquests to its tolerance of different beliefs and promotion of multicultural city centres. We also considered the different experiences of those living within the Mongols realm during their century-long rule.
In this topic, we have learned about the sharp rise and fall of one of the world's greatest empires, as well as the leaders at the heart of it. The Yuan dynasty was full of contrasts, from its violent conquests to its tolerance of different beliefs and promotion of multicultural city centres. We also considered the different experiences of those living within the Mongols realm during their century-long rule.
In this topic, we have learned about the sharp rise and fall of one of the world's greatest empires, as well as the leaders at the heart of it. The Yuan dynasty was full of contrasts, from its violent conquests to its tolerance of different beliefs and promotion of multicultural city centres. We also considered the different experiences of those living within the Mongols realm during their century-long rule.
\end{shapedcutout}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: c01uf027.pdf may appear to be an elaborate shape, but it is stored in a rectangular box.  Maybe OCR software can determine the outline, but otherwise it will require your eyes.  You might overlay a grid to make the process faster, or perhaps a PDF form where you can put check marks on the edges and print out the locations.

Comment: Thanks John for your response. If I got better solution I will post the answer. Cheers!!